# How To use login and password from text file in python selenium to login gmail?

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I am creating an automation to do something Like driver open a Gmail login URL. Get username and password from a text file. And do some task and close the driver. and after 5 sec open the Gmail Login URL again and read next username and password from the text file. text file format is

username1:password1
username2:password2

here is the code

```
with open('gmail.txt', 'r') as file:
       for details in file:
        gmailId, passWord = details.split(':')
        try:
            driver.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin")
            print('Opening URL')
            driver.implicitly_wait(15)
            #WebDriverWait(driver, 3)
            loginBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="identifierId"]')
            slow_typing(loginBox, gmailId)
            print('Entering Username')            
            nextButton = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id ="identifierNext"]')
            nextButton[0].click()
            time.sleep(2)
            passWordBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                '//*[@id ="password"]/div[1]/div / div[1]/input')
            slow_typing(passWordBox, passWord)
            print('Entering Password')
            nextButton = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id ="passwordNext"]')
            nextButton[0].click()
          
            print('Login Successful...!!')
        except:
            pass
            print('Login Failed')
        
        time.sleep(2)
    driver.close()
```

the issue is its using the first username and password again and again after closing driver and opening again. any solution from experts?